# How the dialog window is updating the main table in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog

I have some list of tasks, each task can be edited into new dialog window. After closing the dialog it shows the edited tasks.
So my question is how table ng-model is connected to the ng-model of dialog window.

Please see the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/G50WtHNuJ5fmO0RYcZGg?p=preview)

Task in table is filling through ng-repeat and and expression. When we click edit it open new dialog. In the dialog `ng-model="selectedTask.description"` is defined and in angulur `  $scope.selectedTask = task;' is define. Till here every thing is o.k, But **how when dialog is closed then How updated info is showed in table.**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tasksCtrl">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="#">ToDo API Client Demo</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 1px;"></td>
          <td>
            <b>Task</b>
          </td>
          <td>
            <b>Options</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">

          <td>{{task.title}}</td>
          <td>{{task.description}}</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="beginEdit(task)">Edit</a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add" ng-click="addTask(task)">Add Task</a>
  </div>


  <!-- Start Edit Modal -->

  <div id="edit" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="=1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editDialogLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="editDialogLabel">Edit Task</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="inputTask">Task</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="selectedTask.title" id="inputTask" placeholder="Task title" style="width: 150px;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="inputDescription">Description</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="selectedTask.description" id="inputDescription" placeholder="Description" style="width: 300px;">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input ng-model="selectedTask.done" type="checkbox"> Done
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editTask()" data-dismiss="modal">Update Task</button>
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Edit Modal -->


  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('tasksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("data.json")

      .success(function(response) {

        $scope.tasks = response.tasks;
      });
      $scope.beginEdit = function(task) {
        //alert(task.title);             
        $scope.selectedTask = task;
        $('#edit').modal('show');

      };

      $scope.editTask = function() {
        $('#edit').modal('hide');

      };

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `ng-model` is two-way binding (source to view, and view-> source).

Refer more: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/twowaydatabinding/

Hope this helps.